# model relationship and routes get model id

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have the following route:

```
Route::get('notes/main', function(){

        $destinations = Destination::where('show', '=','1')->get();
        $notes = Destination::find($destination->id)->notes()->get();
        return View::make('notes.main')
        ->with('destinations', $destinations);

});
```

//the relationship models:

```
<?php
class Destination extends Eloquent {
    public function notes()
    {
    return $this->has_many('Note');
    }
}

<?php
class Note extends Eloquent

{
        public function destination()
        {
            return $this->belongs_to('Destination');
        }

}
```

//View:

```
@foreach( $destinations as $destination)

{{ $destination->name}}<br>
{ $notes->destination->text }} // this isn't echoed
@endforeach
```

what's the correct way to filter this and define $destination->id

thanks

How would i Filter the notes in an if statement inside the loop ?
              @if (isset($note->title) != 'shorttext')

```
          @else
           <p> {{ $note->text }} </p>
          @endif  
          @endforeach
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK 
for the last part this worked out at the end
function isset and empty didn't work , strange:

```
@if ($note->title == 'shorttext')
```

Answer (score 1):

You use $destination->id in your Route but it seems to be not defined yet. The question is, what do you want to achieve with your code?
With:

```
$destinations = Destination::where('show', '=','1')->get();
$notes = Destination::find($destination->id)->notes()->get();
```

you are getting only the Notes of one specific destination (so far, $destination is not defined. You could use Destination::all()->first() to get the first, or Destination::find(id), with ID being replaced with the primary key value of the destination you need).

But I guess you don't want it that way. From your Output it seems like you want to have an output with each destination and below each destination the corresponding Notes.

Controller:

```
//gets all the destinations
$destinations = Destination::where('show', '=','1')->get();
return View::make('notes.main')
    ->with('destinations', $destinations);
```

View:

```
@foreach( $destinations as $destination)
  {{ $destination->name}}<br>
  @foreach($destination->notes as $note)
     {{ $note->text }} <br>
  @endforeach
  <hr>
@endforeach
```

Didn't test this, but this way your View would show you all your Destinations and for each Destination all the Notes.

Comment: Your comment seems cut, but I saw I made a mistake in the output. It should not be $destination->notes->text but $note->text. I will edit it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

In your route, your not sending $notes variable to the view.

How I would do it:

```
   $destinations = Destination::where('show', '=','1')->get();
   $destinations->notes = Destination::find($destination->id)->notes()->get();
```

Then in view:

```
@foreach( $destinations as $destination)
   {{ $destination->name}}<br>
   {{ $destination->notes->text }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: i get :Undefined variable: destination

Answer (score 0):

So first you asked a question, I gave you a correct answer. 
You marked my answer as accepted, but later on you edit your initial question to add another question (for which you should create a new thread instead).
Then you create your own answer which is only answering part of your initial question and mark that as the good solution?

I could tell you why your isset and empty did not work, but why should I if you don't value my help at all?